# How do I find the list of available qualifiers for a given EntityProperty?

Tags: entity

If you read the docs for [`EntityProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperty.html) you see it can be used with [`EntityValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) to perform qualified selections of data, improving efficiency of queries, etc.

Unfortunately the docs only say this:

> `EntityProperty[type, pname,{qual1->val1,qual2->val2,…}]`
>   represents a property modified by the qualifier rules `quali->vali`.

and nothing about how to figure out what's valid for `quali`

So how do we do this?

Answer (score 5):

It appears you can do queries on an `EntityProperty` too, with `EntityValue`. There's another question, here, which is what are the valid `EntityProperty` properties, but at least for what we care about we have this:

```
EntityValue[
 EntityProperty["..."],
 "Qualifiers"
 ]
```

Here's a fun example:

```
AssociationThread[
   CanonicalName@#,
   EntityValue[#, "Qualifiers"]
   ] &@RandomSample[EntityProperties@"Country", 10]

<|"ExternalBalance" -> {"CurrencyUnit", "Date", "PercentOfGDP", 
   "TradeSection"}, "ISOCertificationOwnership" -> {"Date"}, 
 "CapitalCity" -> {"Date"}, 
 "BenefitsCostIndex" -> {"Date", "Frequency", "SeasonalAdjustment", 
   "TimeSeriesOperator"}, 
 "RoadSectorGasolineFuelConsumption" -> {"Date", "PerCapita"}, 
 "FederalDebt" -> {"Adjustment", "Date", "FederalDebtHolder", 
   "Frequency", "Modifier", "SeasonalAdjustment", 
   "TimeSeriesOperator"}, 
 "EmploymentToPopulationRatio" -> {"AgeClass", "Date", "Gender"}, 
 "HospitalBedsPer10000Population" -> {"Date"}, 
 "AgriculturalProductionIndex" -> {"Date"}, 
 "TotalFertilityRate" -> {"Date", "DateRange"}|>
```

Then we can use it like so:

```
EntityValue[
  countryclass,
  EntityProperty["Country", 
   "ExternalBalance", {"Date" -> 
     Interval[{DateObject["1992"], DateObject["2005"]}]}
   ]
  ] // Short
```

[image: ts]

But it's not trivial to figure out how these work in general...

```
EntityValue[
  countryclass,
  EntityProperty["Country", 
   "ExternalBalance", {"CurrencyUnit" -> "Euros"}
   ]
  ] // DeleteDuplicates

{Missing["UnknownProperty", {"Country", 
   "ExternalBalance", {"CurrencyUnit" -> "Euros"}}]}

EntityValue[
  countryclass,
  EntityProperty["Country", 
   "ExternalBalance", {"CurrencyUnit" -> Quantity[1, "Euros"]}
   ]
  ] // DeleteDuplicates

{Missing["UnknownProperty", {"Country", 
   "ExternalBalance", {"CurrencyUnit" -> Quantity[1, "Euros"]}}]}
```

Sometimes you can figure out how these properties work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>, which is how I figured out how to do this:

```
EntityValue[
 countryclass,
 EntityProperty["Country", 
  "ExternalBalance", {"PercentOfGDP" -> "PercentOfGDP"}
  ]
 ]

{Quantity[0.703882, "Percent"], Quantity[7.0582, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[4.48768, "Percent"], Quantity[-6.47908, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[0.459015, "Percent"], Quantity[7.57397, "Percent"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Quantity[4.11505, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[32.1342, "Percent"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], Quantity[-1.32907, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[2.01432, "Percent"], Quantity[36.0466, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[11.6811, "Percent"], Quantity[2.42052, "Percent"], 
 Quantity[3.99459, "Percent"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 Quantity[4.20712, "Percent"], Quantity[-1.40457, "Percent"]}
```

Another very interesting place where I *do* know how this works is for the `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` property `"Ranks"` and its qualifier `"Corpus"`:

```
EntityValue[
  EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"],
  EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
   "Ranks", {"Corpus" -> "StackExchange"}],
  "Association"
  ] // TakeSmallest[5]

<|Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Integer"] -> 75, 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Association"] -> 104, 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Real"] -> 142, 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "String"] -> 145, 
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Image"] -> 182|>
```