# How do I find the list of values for an EntityProperty qualifier?

Tags: entity

#### Cross-Post on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1555220?p_p_auth=sMU4BnKm)

---

I have an [`EntityProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperty.html) and [I know how to get its list of qualifiers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186262/38205). Now how do I figure out the possible values these can take programmatically? Here's an example to get us started:

```
EntityValue[
 EntityProperty["Country", "ExternalBalance"],
 "Qualifiers"
 ]

{"CurrencyUnit", "Date", "PercentOfGDP", "TradeSection"
```

Now, say, how do I programmatically determine what `"CurrencyUnit"`, `"TradeSection"`, and `"PercentOfGDP"` can be?

Comment: Is that just `EntityValue[
 EntityProperty["Country", "ExternalBalance"], "QualifierValues"]`?

Comment: That it is. I didn't know that was a possible query. Where's that documented? (is it?)

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure it is.

Comment: Figures. Want to toss that in as the answer?

Comment: @M.R. It is documented in the Details section of the `EntityValue` documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can discover available qualifiers and values for a property like this:

```
EntityValue[ EntityProperty["Country", "ExternalBalance"], "QualifierValues"]
```

I did find one example of this usage - in the Scope section of `EntityValue`  ref page:

[image]